# AWS KMS InvalidCiphertextException: null with Node.js

Tags: node.js, encryption, amazon-kms

I have the following error when I decrypt use aws amplify lamda with Node.js.

```
2023-06-07T22:08:18.316Z    1522c69b-abba-4af9-9318-b1b2f3ae3ecf    ERROR   Decrypt error: InvalidCiphertextException: null
    at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:80:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'InvalidCiphertextException',
  '[__type]': 'See error.__type for details.',
  time: 2023-06-07T22:08:18.314Z,
  requestId: 'fa44fca6-2d05-40c4-8be7-94576d34f231',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 4.312792937378385
}
```

I set up IAM role like this.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUseOfKmsKey",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:ap-northeast-1:1111:key/afeagagh"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also KMS added KMS settings.

KMS console's key id: afeagagh

Then, I set up these lamda's ENV settings according to this solution https://repost.aws/ja/knowledge-center/kms-invalidciphertextexception.

encrypt's lamda ENV(key: KMS_KEY_ID, value: afeagagh)

decrypt's lamda ENV(key: KMS_KEY_ID, value: a decrypted value from afeagagh)

And here is my code.

in encrypt.js

```
async function encryptData(data, keyId) {
  try {
    const encryptCommand = new EncryptCommand({
      KeyId: keyId,
      Plaintext: Buffer.from(data),
    });
    const encryptResponse = await client.send(encryptCommand);
    
    const encryptedData = encryptResponse.CiphertextBlob;
    
    return encryptedData.toString('base64');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

await encryptData(JSON.stringify(paymentId), process.env.KMS_KEY_ID);
```

in decrypt.js

```
async function decryptData(encryptedData) {
  if (!decrypted) {
    const functionName = process.env.AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME
    const kms = new AWS.KMS({ region: 'ap-northeast-1' });
    try {
      const req = {
        CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from(encryptedData, 'base64'),
        EncryptionContext: { LambdaFunctionName: functionName },
      }
      const data = await kms.decrypt(req).promise()
      decrypted = data.Plaintext.toString('ascii')
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Decrypt error:', err)
      throw err
    }
  }
  return decrypted
}

await decryptData(paymentId)
```

The argument of the encryptedData I get is like this `1,2,2,0,120,134,12,192,140,2....`.

I tried to fix this for a couple of days. But it's still not working. Hope if you could give me some way to fix this. Thanks.